# Extracting the value of 2-d gridded field by scatter points in Python

Tags: python, grid, gis, geospatial, netcdf

I have a 2-d gridded files which represents the land use catalogues for the place of interest.
I also have some lat/lon based point distributed in this area.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

## 2-d gridded files
nc_file = "./geo_em.d02.nc"
geo = Dataset(nc_file, 'r')
lu = geo.variables["LU_INDEX"][0,:,:]
lat = geo.variables["XLAT_M"][0,:]  
lon = geo.variables["XLONG_M"][0,:] 

## point files
point = pd.read_csv("./point_data.csv")
plt.pcolormesh(lon,lat,lu)
plt.scatter(point_data.lon,cf_fire_data.lat, color ='r')
```

[image]

I want to extract the values of the 2-d gridded field which those points belong, but I found it is difficult to define a simple function to solve that.

Is there any efficient method to achieve it?

Any advices would be appreciated.

### PS

I have uploaded my files here

[1. nc_file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FExIttr8RxVJG_Pjqa928Oa1RIvrdoUz)
[2. point_file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xOcH8i1CjNmUpaILQ-R6wzUaguJPsk9l)

Answer (score 1):

I can propose solution like this, where I just loop over the points and select the data based on the distance from the point.

```
#/usr/bin/env ipython
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
# --------------------------------------
## 2-d gridded files
nc_file = "./geo_em.d02.nc"
geo = Dataset(nc_file, 'r')
lu = geo.variables["LU_INDEX"][0,:,:]
lat = geo.variables["XLAT_M"][0,:]  
lon = geo.variables["XLONG_M"][0,:] 

## point files
point = pd.read_csv("./point_data.csv")
plt.pcolormesh(lon,lat,lu)
#plt.scatter(point_data.lon,cf_fire_data.lat, color ='r') 
# --------------------------------------------
# get data for points:
dataout=[];
lon_ratio=np.cos(np.mean(lat)*np.pi/180.0)
for ii in range(len(point)):
    plon,plat = point.lon[ii],point.lat[ii]
    distmat=np.sqrt(1./lon_ratio*(lon-plon)**2+(lat-plat)**2)
    kk=np.where(distmat==np.min(distmat));
    dataout.append([float(lon[kk]),float(lat[kk]),float(lu[kk])]);
# ---------------------------------------------
```